# WPF Popup placement relative to main window

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup

I have a WPF application that uses one window as main window. Now I want to display various popups centered in the window. This works fine when the popup is placed inside the window. However, I have implemented the popups as user control; meaning that the main window contains a user controls which itself contains the actual popup. So the UI element tree looks like this:

```
Window --> UserControlPopup --> Popup
```

The popup inside the user control is declared like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="X.Custom_Controls.ErrorPopup"
         ...
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:X.Custom_Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="360" d:DesignWidth="500">

<Popup Name="errorPopup" Height="360" Width="500" Placement="Center" StaysOpen="True" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow}">
    ...
</Popup> </UserControl>
```

The **mainWindow** element name is the one of my main window, which is declared as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="X.MainWindow" x:Name="mainWindow" ...>
```

The problem is that the popup is not placed in the center, but on the left side. So my guess is that the popup cannot resolve the elementName properly (since it's a child of a child of the mainWindow). Does anyone know how I can solve this issue in XAML?

**Update:** the solution was to use

```
PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
```

Comment: have you tried relative source? `PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MainWindow}}"`

Comment: "MainWindow" did not work, as the type is no recognized by WPF. However, with "Window" it works: PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}". Thanks!

Comment: @Cleo you are able to answer your own questions. I would suggest posting your solution as an answer and accepting it - if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the following as PlacementTarget:

```
PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to acces your main window through `x:Reference`. This one should work:

```
<MainWindow x:Name="mainWindow">
    <UserControl Tag="{x:Reference mainWindow}">
</MainWindow>
<UserControl x:Name="userControl">
<PopUp PlacementTarget="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=userControl}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Such a way you can use your UserControl in another Controls/UserControls and you will not need to modify it, just set the Tag property from outside, if you use {RelativeSource AncestorType=Window} you will need to modify it.

Comment: Nope does not work, throws an 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' at runtime ("Reference could not be resolved"). I guess that's because "mainWindow" is declared in another file (or namespace?).

Comment: I have thought, the PopUp in MainWindow.. I have edited my answer.